# How to insert a variable into a query parameter?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I need to put a variable into query parameter.

I have this situation:

```
<?php

$variable = get_field(loop_category);

$catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=***VARIABLE-HERE***');
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
```

How can i do this?

Sorry for my bad english, i`m not english spoker!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name="' . $variable  . '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$catquery = new WP_Query("category_name={$variable}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array to `WP_Query`

```
 <?php

 $variable = get_field(loop_category);
 $args = array(
  'category_name' => $variable
 );
 $catquery = new WP_Query( $args);
 while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
```